# Unknown protocol when trying to connect to remote host with stunnel

Tags: tunneling, stunnel

I'm trying to set up a stunnel for WebDav on Windows. I want to connect 80 port on my local interface to 443 on another machine in my network. I can ping the machine remote machine. However when I use the tunnel, I'm getting this error all the time

```
SSL state (accept): before/accept initialization
SSL_accept: 140760FC: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

There is nothing in the logs on the other machine and here's my stunnel connection config

```
[https]
accept  = 127.0.0.2:80
connect = 10.0.0.60:443
verify = 0
```

I've set it up to accept all certificates so this shouldn't be a problem with a self-signed certificate remote host uses.

Does anyone knows what might be the problem that this connection cannot be eastablished?

Comment: Are you using stunnel, which is a piece of software, or are you trying to create a secure tunnel? Your question appears to have the terms confused.

Comment: I'm using stunnel the app. http://www.stunnel.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution for this problem. I've been using SSL in server mode when I actually needed client mode.

Comment: Care to share the solution with us? Would be most appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are accessing your local host with http, but looks like your remote host is already https. stunnel is meant for reverse cases, when local services do not support SSL.

Why can't you just go directly with https/webdav on the remote machine and bypass stunnel completely?

Comment: I'm doing a proof of concept. This SLL tunnel is a part of a larger app and I'm going to implement it on my own because I need several modifications. I just want to test how stable this kind of solution is.